# how to replace &nbsp; from my string in php

Tags: php, custom-code

below are my string, get from mail server using imap.

```
"i have string get from mail

Hello Everyone
I am comment from RTE&nbsp;
let me know about extra characters&nbsp;

Thank You"
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

check this code. i think it will help you

```
<?php 
 $string = "let me know about extra characters&nbsp;";
 $string = str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $string);
 echo $string;
 echo "<br>";
 // check 2
 $string = "let me know about extra characters&nbsp;";
 $string = preg_replace("/\s|&nbsp;/",' ',$string);
 echo $string;
```